# Add Python packages as dependency when building a VS Code extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VS Code extension that assumes that the user already has a particular Python package installed on their system.

What could be the possible approaches to install that Python package to the user's machine when the user installs my VS Code extension.

I was able to think of a few ways to do so but couldn't find any resources on the internet validating my approaches:

1. creating a subprocess from inside the VS Code extension and calling `pip install` if  VS Code is allowed to make such a privileged install to the user's machine without having any special/admin rights?
2. adding that package as a dependency in the `package.json` so it gets installed when the user tried to install the extension? Is there a way to add Python packages as dependencies?

Comment: bad idea, don't install in the system python, most users have a virtual environment and you don't know which one and if it is active or even created

Comment: @rioV8 thanks, makes sense! Can you suggest a possible solution?

Comment: Execute certain Python commands in the workspace when the extension needs to detect such packages and show the users that they should install them in whatever ways they like. Make sure those commands work for both virtual environments and non-virtual.

Comment: thanks, @LexLi sounds like a doable idea.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good idea, because different users will use different Python versions and python environments. When you specify a specific Python version, is the cost of using the extensions you designed a little too high?

Moreover, with the update of Python version, your extensions also need to design new specific dependent versions.

I suggest that you try to let users customize as **vscode** recognizes **Python interpreter**, otherwise the applicable population will not too much.